# How can I delete an Empty with it's dependent objects?

Tags: objects

Hi I'm hoping someone can help me.

I'm running Blender 2.82 on Windows 10 with a 3.10 GHz 4 core processor and 16 gig of RAM.

When I delete an Empty (with multiple objects within it) the dependent objects (I think children is the proper term?) remain in the scene, but are transformed to astronomical sizes - 1000's of meters instead of mm.

I seem to have to delete each object individually, which takes forever.
Is there a way of deleting the empty along with it's dependent objects at the same time?

Having read the posts on this site, I've made sure that I'm in Object Mode before I try deleting anything.

Answer (score 2):

Select your parent object then go to Select > Select grouped (shortcut  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>G</kbd> ) and choose "Children". That will select every children and their children and so on. Then you can delete them like any other object.

Answer (score 1):

While pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> allows to select the children and parents and other dependent categories, it does not select the object and it's children in one go, means you would have to select the parent object additionaly.

I would suggest to just right click on the object in the outliner and use "Select Hierachy", followed by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

That way the empty/parent and it's entire hierachy/children and their children ... are deleted in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys! Having tried all the suggestions above, I find the right click and "Select Hierarchy" approach works for me best as it deletes everything in one fell swoop.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped, should you consider the case closed, please also consider to accept the answer so others see it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> you can also select the main parent and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to select children and sub children level by level.